# How to use separate functions to dynamically compose a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I have a function that walks down a simple tree and calls functions at each step to print a menu:

```
renderMenuFx(menu, renderFx) {
    renderFx.startMenu()
    for (const entry of menu) {
        renderFx.startEntry()
        renderFx.renderEntry(entry.path.join(""), entry.title)
        if (entry.menuEntries) {
            this.renderMenuFx(entry.menuEntries, renderFx)
        }
        renderFx.endEntry()
    }
    renderFx.endMenu()
}
```

and it works when logging to console:

```
this.renderMenuFx(tree, {
    startMenu() { console.log('<ul>') },
    endMenu() { console.log('</ul>') },
    startEntry() { console.log('<li>') },
    endEntry() { console.log('</li>') },
    renderEntry(path, title) { console.log(`<a href="${path}">${title}</a>`) },
})
```

But it doesn't when I try to render it in React:

```
<div>

{
    f.renderMenu(this.tree, {
        startMenu() { return ( <ul> ) },
        endMenu() { return ( </ul> ) },
        startEntry() { return ( <li> ) },
        endEntry() { return ( </li> ) },
        renderEntry(path, title) { return ( <a href={path}>{title}</a> ) },
    })
}

</div>
```

Actually, the issue is that it doesn't compile, giving:

```
./src/components/Menu/MenuDyn.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (141:37)

  139 |                     f.renderMenu(this.tree, {
  140 |                         startMenu() { return ( <ul> ) },
> 141 |                         endMenu() { return ( </ul> ) },
      |                                     ^
```

I'm obviously doing it wrong: what's the correct way to handle such situation?

Comment: Your login test and the jsx functions do different things. I’m pretty sure JSX elements have to be closed. So it’s not possible to render just an opening/closing tag.

Comment: Consider changing the perspective. Each “HTML” tag in JSX is actually a function (React.createElement)

Comment: it's quite simple ... pass tree as prop to some node component ... node renders children subnodes passing subtrees (or end-nodes) [as props]

Comment: @xadm (simple to some, difficult for others. Consider writing an answer?)

Answer (score 1):

Simple example to start experiments:

in some `<Menu menu={someData} />` class component

```
render () {
  return (
    <ul>
      {this.props.menu.map((entry) => (
        <Entry key={entry.id} data={entry}></Entry>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

rendered (functional) subcomponent:

```
const Entry = props => (
  <li>
    {props.data.title}
    {props.data.menuEntries && (
      <Menu menu={props.data.menuEntries} />
    )}
  </li>
)
```

Comment: Yup, thanks. I found some references about recursive React components and came up with something similar; the only thing I don't like is that in this way the tree structure is explicit in the rendering code, whereas in the function-based one it's not - or, better, it is factorized in a single place.

Comment: @watery usually it's full of options, conditions ... you can explore other possibilities like https://github.com/iannbing/react-simple-tree-menu ... simple in use but it can be less readable